# Problem Reading PIC18F4550 Input

Tags: microcontroller, pic, embedded, programming, input

Hi I am facing some problem with Reading the input from a **PIC18f4550** , for a simple arrangement where when a switch on (switch = 1), few led should glow., and on releasing the switch the led should go off (switch = 0),. On providing some volts across a pin (RA0 or RA1)- the leds should glow but I am getting no success in doing so.
I am using MPLAB IDE AND C18 compiler. tried with MPLABX and XC8 compiler too.

I wanted to take input from RA0 and RA1 , with a two push switch. And glow leds on RD7-RD4.
I made a simple if then else statement, inside a while(1) loop to do so.

```
    #include <p18f4550.h>
    #define switch1  PORTAbits.RA0   // two switches
    #define switch2  PORTAbits.RA1
    #define led1    LATDbits.LATD7   // defining led’s for making life easy
    #define led2    LATDbits.LATD6
    #define led3    LATDbits.LATD5
    #define led4    LATDbits.LATD4

    void main (void)
            {
                    // IO settings
                    /* tired both ways*/

            TRISbits.RA0=1   //making input for switch 1
            TRISbits.TRISA1=1  //making input for switch 2

            TRISDbits.TRISD7 = 0;   // RD7 to RD4 set to output for led.
            TRISDbits.TRISD6 = 0;
            TRISDbits.TRISD5= 0;
            TRISDbits.TRISD4 = 0;

            ADCON1bits.PCFG0 = 1;        // making all pins digital.
            ADCON1bits.PCFG1 = 1; 
            ADCON1bits.PCFG2 = 1;     // referred Data Sheet Page:262
            ADCON1bits.PCFG3 = 1;

              while(1)
                {      if(switch1 == 1)   
                            {    led1 = 1;   
                                 led2 = 1;
                                 led3 = 1;
                                 led4 = 1;          }

         else if (switch1 == 0)  // on reading no voltage 
                            {     led1 =  0;
                                  led2 =  0;
                                  led3 =  0;
                                  led4 =  0;  }                                    
                               else { }
                          }  
   }
```

It did not work out well.. the leds on RD7-RD4 keeps glowing all the time no matter what I do.

I tried to change the

```
        PORTAbits.RA0   to  LATAbits.LATA0  but still no help.
```

I did little bit of research and someone recommended me to turn the ADC value off and after looking up datasheet setting. I turned the adc off

```
        ADCON0bits.ADON = 0;  //turn off the ADC
```

Checked with the circuit on breadboard. Everything but still situation same.
Someone further recommended that , it’s a better idea to turn off the comparator. Hence I turned off the comparator again.

```
     CMCON = 0x07;     // comparator off.

     ADCON1=0x0F;  //All pins digital
```

I built entire thing again from scratch but still no success. I push the switch on or off. The leds on RD7-RD4 only of port D keeps glowing all the time :’( .. Here I am please help me.

PS: [Just to add up, I also thought may be my pic18f4550 has gone bad. Hence I tested a code to blink led on pic18f4550 http://goo.gl/PosRgg from a website it worked fine… hence I am sure my pic184550 is has not gone bad.] Please help and recommend where I gone wrong, i have been trying since 3 days now :'(

Comment: How exactly have you connected your switch to the processor? Does the line with "if (switch1 = = 0)" really have a space between the two equal signs?

Comment: it would give an error if there would be any space in between "switch == 0" on mplab ide. The Switch is connected with VSS of the pic18f4550 5v. when the pin in ON - 5v goes into RA0 of the microcontroller.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how you have connected the switch. It's connected with VSS of the 5V? What does that mean? Is there a pullup or pulldown resistor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think ADCON will make a difference in this case seeing PORTD pins you're using are multiplexed with Enhanced PWM Mode and the Streaming Parallel Port (SPP), rather than Analog Input Module, which take priority over port I/O

You'll want to disable the Enhanced PWM that're also multiplexed with PORTD pins. 
Also you'll probbably want disable SPP, by clearing SPPCON register bit 0 (SPPEN) to 0

[image]

So a solution in this case can be to configure CCP1CON to anything but Dual or Quad PWM by setting CCP1CON to 00xx 11xx
[image]

Comment: thanks for replying, do u mean  Something like SPPCON = 0; 
SSPCON1 = 0; ? How to i disable the pwm on portD . hey what if i drop the whole idea of using port D and make the setting on for portB, Like from RB0 to RB4 ? will that solve my problem ?

Comment: @Sanju updated answer. That's one approach but same algorithm of thought though, look up what is multiplexed with the alternative port, and see if you need to disable any modules interfering with it. SPPCON (SPP) communication not SSP (serial)